# Kotlin NDArray with a lambda constructor with generic return type

Tags: arrays, generics, kotlin, type-erasure

I'm trying to create a very simple generic NDArray class in Kotlin that takes a lambda expression as an init function.

```
class NDArray<T>(i: Int, j: Int, f: (Int) -> T) {
    val values: Array<T> =  Array(i * j, f)
}
```

A typical usage would be:

```
fun main(args: Array<String>){
    val m = NDArray(4, 4, ::zero)
}

fun zero(i: Int) =  0.0
```

My problem is that the Kotlin compiler complains on the initialisation of values in the constructor

```
values = Array(i * j, f)
```

by saying "Cannot use 'T' as reified type parameter. Use class instead". Why ?

**EDIT:**

If I instead replace the Kotlin Array implementation with my own MyArray it compiles:

```
class NDArray<T>(i: Int, j: Int, f: (Int) -> T) {
    val values: MyArray<T> =  MyArray(i * j, f)
}

class MyArray<T>(i:Int, init: (Int) -> T) {
    ...
}
```

Not sure why Kotlin treats MyArray differently from a regular Array when both have the same constructor ?

Comment: why not simply `class NDArray<T>(i:Int, j:Int, f: (Int) -> T) {
    val values: Array<Int> =  Array<Int>(i*j,f)
}` ?

Comment: Definitely more concise but the problem still remains since Array should be of type T, not Int.

Comment: non-idiomatic Kotlin code is hard to read. Please see the edit

Comment: Nice and concise. Edit accepted, thanks !

Comment: for `MyArray` to act like `Array`, it has to have a `reifiled T` generic parameter. For now it is only allowed for `inline` functions

Comment: Still doesn't explain why the compiler sees a difference between MyArray and Array in the example above. As far as I can tell from the reference doc Array<T> is not declared with reifeid keyword. Maybe compiler magic since this is a "special" Kotlin type ?

Comment: yes, magic is implied. Please see my edit to the yole's answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Creating a Java array requires specifying an element type. In the case of your class, the element type is provided only as a type parameter of the class, and generics in Java are erased at runtime. Because of that, the element type of the array is not known, and it's not possible to create it.

If you would want to create a custom wrapper around standard `Array<T>`, it would have to look like the following:

```
class NDArray<reified T>(i:Int, j:Int, init: (Int) -> T) {
    val arr = Array<T>(i * j, init)
}
```

The `reified` keyword means that your `T` is not erased, and may be used in places where a real class is needed, like calling the `Array()` constructor.

Note that this **syntax is not supported** for class constructors, but it is still useful for factory functions (must be `inline`d)

```
fun <reified T> arrayFactory(i:Int, j:Int, init: (Int) -> T) = Array<T>(i * j, init)
```

Comment: Figured that it had something todo with type-erasure. If you look at it from a JVM perspective I can see the problem of creating a array of generic type T[] in runtime. From a Kotlin perspective I'm a bit puzzled still, please see edit.

Comment: Basically a wrapping a Array<T>() is not possible without using a factory pattern ? Btw, please see edit

Answer (score 1):

Based on input from yole and voddan this is the best solution I found to the problem so far:

```
class NDArray<T>(val values: Array<T> ){

    companion object Factory{
        inline operator fun <reified T>invoke(i: Int, j: Int, noinline init: (Int) -> T) = NDArray(Array(i * j,init))
    }
}
```

This allows the usage of reified as a constructor by using a companion object. Construction calling convention can be done using operator invoke. This works now:

```
fun main(args: Array<String>){
    val m = NDArray(4,4, ::zero)
}

fun zero(i:Int) =  0.0
```

The only problem ( except for the convoluted syntax invoke() ) is that the NDArray constructor need to be public. Is there a better way perhaps ?

NOTE! Following issues [KT-11182](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-11182) affects this design pattern