# Instantiating generic array in Kotlin

Tags: generics, kotlin

Why this doesn't compile? I get compile error in 3 line

> Cannot use T as reified type parameter. Use class instead

```
class Matrix2d<T>(val rows: Int, val cols: Int, init: (Int, Int) -> T) {

   var data = Array(rows * cols, { i ->
      val r = Math.floor(i.toDouble() / cols).toInt()
      init(r, i - r * cols)
   })

   operator fun get(row: Int, col: Int): T = data[row * cols + col]

   operator fun set(row: Int, col: Int, v: T) = {
      data[row * cols + col] = v
   }
}
```

**Solution**

I added a factory function which looks like a second constructor but implemented in inline function

```
class Matrix2d<T>(val rows: Int, val cols: Int, private val data: Array<T>) {

   companion object {
      operator inline fun <reified T> invoke(rows: Int, cols: Int, init: (Int, Int) -> T): Matrix2d<T> {
         return Matrix2d(rows, cols, Array(rows * cols, { i ->
            val r = Math.floor(i.toDouble() / cols).toInt()
            init(r, i - r * cols)
         }))
      }
   }

   init {
      if (rows * cols != data.size) throw IllegalArgumentException("Illegal array size: ${data.size}")
   }

   operator fun get(row: Int, col: Int): T = data[row * cols + col]

   operator fun set(row: Int, col: Int, v: T) {
      data[row * cols + col] = v
   }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Kotlin NDArray with a lambda constructor with generic return type](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35581867/kotlin-ndarray-with-a-lambda-constructor-with-generic-return-type)

Answer (score 27, accepted):

JVM arrays, on which Kotlin arrays are mapped to, require the element type to be known at compile time to create an instance of array.

So you can instantiate `Array<String>` or `Array<Any>`, but not `Array<T>` where `T` is a type parameter, representing the type that is erased at compile time and hence is unknown. 
To specify that a type parameter must be known at compile time it is marked with `reified` modifier.

There are several options, what you can do in this situation:

1. Use `MutableList<T>` for storing elements, which doesn't require reified T:

   ```
   // MutableList function, available in Kotlin 1.1
   val data = MutableList(rows * cols, { i ->
      val r = i / cols
      init(r, i % cols)
   })
   // or in Kotlin 1.0
   val data = mutableListOf<T>().apply {
       repeat(rows * cols) { i ->
           val r = i / cols
           add(init(r, i % cols))
       }
   }
   ```
2. Create an array from an inline function with reified type parameter:

   ```
   inline fun <reified T> Matrix2d(val rows: Int, val cols: Int, init: (Int, Int) -> T) = 
       Matrix2d(rows, cols, Array(rows * cols, { .... })

   class Matrix2d<T> 
       @PublishedApi internal constructor(
           val rows: Int, val cols: Int,
           private val data: Array<T>
       )
   ```
3. Use `Array<Any?>` as the storage, and cast its values to `T` in `get` function:

   ```
   val data = Array<Any?>(rows * cols, { .... })

   operator fun get(row: Int, col: Int): T = data[row * cols + col] as T
   ```
4. Pass a parameter of type `Class<T>` or `KClass<T>` to constructor and use java reflection to create an instance of array.

Comment: Thanks for explanation, I like the second way. I updated my post and code works properly, but now I have a public constructor in Matrix2d class which can be used by all, and it's confusing, because I have a third parameter as an array. And if I use that constructor I should pass the number of rows and columns. 
I wanted to specify contructor scope to private, but it's not available for inline function. How can I solve this problem in a different way?

Comment: Use internal constructor, though to call it from public inline function, you have to annotate it with @PublishedApi annotation (available in Kotlin 1.1). I'll update the example.

Answer (score 3):

Personally, the best workaround for me was:

```
@Suppress("UNCHECKED_CAST")
var pool: Array<T?> = arrayOfNulls<Any?>(initialCapacity) as Array<T?>
```

Comment: This solution is just as viable as solution 3 in the selected answer; just probably should have private access.

Comment: I don't think this works, it throws a ClassCastException with a misleading error message (see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54536895/cannot-be-cast-to-class-because-they-are-in-unnamed-module-of-loader-app) but the fact still remains that it cannot do the cast