# Two dimensional generic Array provider

Tags: arrays, generics, multidimensional-array, kotlin

I'm trying to implement generic two dimensional array provider in Kotlin:

```
public fun <T> array2dim(sizeOuter: Int, sizeInner: Int): Array<Array<T>>
            = Array(sizeOuter) { Array(sizeInner) }
```

but can't figure out how to overcome the issue.

The compiler says: **Type interface failed: Not enough information to infer parameter T in
constructor Array
(
size: Int,
init: (Int) → T
)
Please specify it explicitly.**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, your inner [`Array` constructor](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/-array/-init-.html) call is missing its second `init` parameter, the lambda where you create the initial elements that the `Array` will contain. If you, say, want to fill it all with the same element, you could pass that as a parameter:

```
fun <T> array2dim(sizeOuter: Int, sizeInner: Int, element: T): Array<Array<T>>
            = Array(sizeOuter) { Array(sizeInner) { element } }
```

You could also use the outer and inner indexes and create initial elements based on those:

```
fun <T> array2dim(sizeOuter: Int, 
                  sizeInner: Int, 
                  createElement: (Int, Int) -> T): Array<Array<T>>
        = Array(sizeOuter) { outerIndex ->
              Array(sizeInner) { innerIndex ->
                  createElement(outerIndex, innerIndex)
              } 
          }
```

If you have nothing to initialize your `Array` with when you create it, consider creating nullable inner `Array`s with [`arrayOfNulls`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/array-of-nulls.html).

---

These will still give you an error about not being able to access `T` - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41946516/4465208) to a related question for the explanation, but you'll need to mark your `T` as `reified` (and consequently, your function as `inline`):

```
inline fun <reified T> array2dim(sizeOuter: Int, sizeInner: Int, element: T)
            : Array<Array<T>>
            = Array(sizeOuter) { Array(sizeInner) { element } }
```