# problem with java 17, spring AOP when i call soap service

Tags: spring, soap, aop

i got this error when i try to call my saop service.
i am in java 17 and i use jakarta(xml.bind, activation...), com.sun.xml.ws rt , jaxvs-ri, jaxb-runtime jaxb-impl.

java.lang.ClassCastException: class org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation cannot be cast to class x.x.x.x.x.x.x.GeRessourceById
(org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation and x.x.x.x.x.x.x.GeRessourceById are in unnamed module of loader java.net.URLClassLoader @4cf4d528)

Where do you think this problem comes from?.

I'm trying to call a wsdl generated Soap service in Java 8. I transformed the generated class to match the Java 17 spec with Jakarta import. I'm trying to test under Tomcat 10

Comment: hello and welcome to SO, please use correct code formatting for code/logs snippets and show us actual code you have use (you AOP Aspect class perhaps)

Comment: Do go through SO [Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54536895/4214241)