# ClassCastException Using Fabric8 to Retrieve Custom Resource Spec

Tags: java, spring-boot, kubernetes, fabric8

I am using Fabric8 to perform CRUD operations on various K8S custom resources. When reading a resource and attempting to retrieve its `spec`, I am experiencing a `ClassCastException` between `RawExtension` and my POJO which defines the resource spec `MyCRDSpec`

`java.lang.ClassCastException: class io.fabric8.kubernetes.api.model.runtime.RawExtension cannot be cast to class my.package.MyCRDSpec`

The custom resource class

```
@Group("my.group")
@Version("v1alpha1")
public class MyCRD extends CustomResource<MyCRDSpec, MyCRDStatus> implements
    Namespaced {
}
```

Spec POJO

```
@Data
@Builder
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class MyCRDSpec implements KubernetesResource {

  private String id;
  private String name;
  ...
}
```

Status POJO

```
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class MyCRDStatus implements KubernetesResource {
  private String msg;
}
```

And this is how I'm reading the resource and attempting to retrieve the `spec`

```
try (final KubernetesClient client = new KubernetesClientBuilder().build()) {
    final MixedOperation<MyCRD, KubernetesResourceList<MyCRD>, Resource<MyCRD>> crdClient = 
        client.resources(MyCRD.class);
    final MyCRD crd= crdClient.inNamespace("ns").withName("my-existing-custom-resource-name").get();
    return crd.getSpec().getName();
}
```

The reason for retrieving the spec is I want to be able to map to a domain object using the properties contained in the custom resource. However, I encounter this `ClassCastException` each time. Logging the full result of `getSpec()` shows that it appears to be bound to `RawExtension` rather than `MyCRDSpec` as expected

`spec=RawExtension(super=AnyType(value={...}))`

I've been following [this](https://itnext.io/handling-kubernetes-custom-resources-in-java-using-fabric8-kubernetes-client-part-2-typed-cc0560d9af0d) and [this](https://developers.redhat.com/articles/2023/01/04/programming-kubernetes-custom-resources-java#creating_the_custom_resource_definition) as guides so far. I have also tried changing my client configuration but nothing has yielded any results.

I haven't included the CRD yaml definition or how I'm creating the custom resources because that functionality is working as expected, but it's very similar to my code above and in those guides. I am able to view both the CRD and my created resources in cluster without issue.

I am using `spring-cloud-kubernetes-fabric8-all` version `3.1.0` and JDK 21.

**EDIT**

The `ClassCastException` also contains an error about the class loader

`io.fabric8.kubernetes.api.model.runtime.RawExtension and my.package.MyCRDSpec are in unnamed module of loader org.springframework.boot.loader.launch.LaunchedClassLoader`

Having checked some of the answers in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54536895/cannot-be-cast-to-class-they-are-in-unnamed-module-of-loader-app), I tried replacing Lombok annotations with manual getters/setters but this made no difference.

***EDIT 2***

Progress. Annotating `MyCRDSpec` with `@JsonDeserialize()` solves the problem. The question is, *why do I need to do this?* Is there something in the Fabric8 client setting a custom deserializer unexpectedly or incorrectly?

Comment: Is it possible to share some reproducer? Are you using lombok?

Comment: Yes, I am using Lombok. I don't have a reproducer to share, if it's absolutely required I could put something together into a repo though

Comment: Please see the most recent edit for progress updates

Comment: Hmm, strange. I checked CRD classes in [our existing tests](https://github.com/fabric8io/kubernetes-client/blob/main/kubernetes-tests/src/test/java/io/fabric8/kubernetes/client/mock/crd/CronTabSpec.java) but they don't seem to have this annotation, but a `toString()` implementation. And they don't seem to implement KubernetesResource

Comment: Yeah I saw the `toString()` implementation in your classes. I'll try removing the Jackson annotation and adding `toString()` and report back

Comment: Can confirm that adding a `toString()` implementation and removing the Jackson annotation results in the same `ClassCastException`. The reason for trying the annotation in the first place was I found it on an [example class](https://github.com/fabric8io/kubernetes-client/blob/main/kubernetes-examples/src/main/java/io/fabric8/kubernetes/examples/crds/DummySpec.java) in the Fabric8 repo

Comment: What about `implements KubernetesResource` ? Does it work if you remove it?

Comment: Apologies for the delayed response. Removing the implementation of `KubernetesResource` does indeed fix the issue. I guess that the `Spec` and `Status` classes don't need to implement it. If you want to create an answer below I'd gladly accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need extend `MyCRDSpec` and `MyCRDStatus` with `KubernetesResource`. Extending them with this class seems to register it with [KubernetesDeserializer](https://github.com/fabric8io/kubernetes-client/blob/0c80a66d10bf7096864246ce453413e0da4edbd2/kubernetes-model-generator/kubernetes-model-core/src/main/java/io/fabric8/kubernetes/internal/KubernetesDeserializer.java#L210) that tries to map it as an actual Kubernetes resource (like Deployment, Pod etc). The issue was getting fixed by adding `@JsonDeserialize(using = com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonDeserializer.None.class)` because this configured Jackson to not use KubernetesDeserializer.