# Deserializing Generic Type with GSON

Tags: java, json, kotlin, gson, deserialization

I've already seen this question:

[Deserializing Generic Types with GSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18397342/deserializing-generic-types-with-gson)

but my use case is different, what I need is just convert json to `T`, and not `List<T>` or similar..
Here is what i need in code:

```
 val type: Type = object : TypeToken<T>() {}.type
```

and then

```
Gson().fromJson<T>(json, type)
```

But it's not working. It returns LinkedHashMap or something like that, but not the class represented by T. When I replace T with actual class type, it works, but with T it's not working. Could someone give me some advice ? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use `Gson().fromJson(json, T.class);` no TypeToken needed

Comment: thanks for your answer, it lead me to the solution, which is in answer I posted...

Comment: that didn't work for me, no type in kotlin has .class!

Answer (score 3):

I've found solution:
Using just `T::class.java` was not enough, It gave me compilation error:

> Cannot use T as reified type parameter. Use class instead

So I had to find solution how to fix it. What I had to do was change name of the function from this:

```
fun <T> myFunction
```

to this:

```
inline fun <reified T> myFunction
```

after that, no compilation error is shown, and code works
more info about this topic is here : 
[Instantiating generic array in Kotlin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41941102/instantiating-generic-array-in-kotlin/41946516#41946516)

and the deserialization looks like this:

```
 Gson().fromJson(json, T::class.java)
```